# Extracting specific dates from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have to columns in my table (check_in and checkout). Both  of them has this format `dd-mm-yyyy`. I want to check if there is any date available between my two paramaters(inputs).

I tried like this:

```
select * from rezervare where date(check_out) > date('my_checkout_input')
```

but this works only in a few cases. If i have a reservation between  **12-03-2015 - 15-03-2015** and another reservation between **17-03-2015 and 20-03-2015**. It will not take the date between **16-03-2015** as a free date. Can you give me some ideas ?

Comment: And those are MySQL date/datetime fields of course

Comment: Sidenote: You should be storing dates in MySQL datetime format YYYY-mm-dd less headaches. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: Actually the column format are declared as text.

Comment: That makes it all that much harder to query. You'll need to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: For between dates, see `BETWEEN` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table rezervare (
    id int auto_increment,
    check_in varchar(10),
    checkout varchar(10),
    primary key (id)
);
insert into rezervare values
    (null, '12-03-2015', '12-03-2015'),
    (null, '13-03-2015', '13-03-2015'),
    (null, '14-03-2015', '14-03-2015'),
    (null, '15-03-2015', '15-03-2015'),
    (null, '16-03-2015', '16-03-2015'),
    (null, '17-03-2015', '17-03-2015'),
    (null, '19-03-2015', '19-03-2015'),
    (null, '20-03-2015', '20-03-2015')
;

select * from rezervare;
+----+------------+------------+
| id | check_in   | checkout   |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 12-03-2015 | 12-03-2015 |
|  2 | 13-03-2015 | 13-03-2015 |
|  3 | 14-03-2015 | 14-03-2015 |
|  4 | 15-03-2015 | 15-03-2015 |
|  5 | 16-03-2015 | 16-03-2015 |
|  6 | 17-03-2015 | 17-03-2015 |
|  7 | 19-03-2015 | 19-03-2015 |
|  8 | 20-03-2015 | 20-03-2015 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

If your schema same as this, you can't use date function, because:

```
select id, date(check_in), date(checkout) from rezervare ;
+----+----------------+----------------+
| id | date(check_in) | date(checkout) |
+----+----------------+----------------+
|  1 | NULL           | NULL           |
|  2 | NULL           | NULL           |
|  3 | NULL           | NULL           |
|  4 | NULL           | NULL           |
|  5 | NULL           | NULL           |
|  6 | NULL           | NULL           |
|  7 | NULL           | NULL           |
|  8 | NULL           | NULL           |
+----+----------------+----------------+
```

But you can use between, in my example it works fine:

```
select * from rezervare where checkout between '12-03-2015' and '15-03-2015';
+----+------------+------------+
| id | check_in   | checkout   |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 12-03-2015 | 12-03-2015 |
|  2 | 13-03-2015 | 13-03-2015 |
|  3 | 14-03-2015 | 14-03-2015 |
|  4 | 15-03-2015 | 15-03-2015 |
+----+------------+------------+

select * from rezervare where checkout > '14-03-2015';
+----+------------+------------+
| id | check_in   | checkout   |
+----+------------+------------+
|  4 | 15-03-2015 | 15-03-2015 |
|  5 | 16-03-2015 | 16-03-2015 |
|  6 | 17-03-2015 | 17-03-2015 |
|  7 | 19-03-2015 | 19-03-2015 |
|  8 | 20-03-2015 | 20-03-2015 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

But true way - alter table and use correct date type.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should use `int` to store the date as a timestamp. 
The PHP function `date()` could transform timestamp to date in the format you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Use the BETWEEN function:

```
SELECT *
    FROM rezervare
    WHERE (date BETWEEN '2010-03-12' AND '2010-03-15')
```

Comment: I do not have a date column. I have check_in and checkout